# Typo3: Editor account with access to flexforms

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have set up an account for Editors in my system, so they can access only whats relevant for their role. But I found an issue:

I have the extension [multicolumn](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/multicolumn) in my system, and I have gave access to the editors, but when they click on the "configuration" tab, all they see is empty content. I think they dont have access to the flexforms inside.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What TYPO3 version? Did you check if you use the lastest version of multicolumn? Maybe try to use gridelements instead.

Comment: version 4.4.10. The extension is up to date. Im too invested already in this extension to change it.

Comment: Well, the latest version is 4.4.15 (with security fixes), so you better update your TYPO3.

Comment: Best is to contact the developer and please double check your access list. Also have a look for JS error and PHP errors. I do not use this extensions and the flexform does not use exclude fields itself (there was a bug with this feature), so I can not help you any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue might be caused by the following TYPO3 core bug [#31831](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/31831). This bug is fixed in the currently maintained releases of TYPO3 (4.5, 4.6, 4.7). Afterwards you may have to edit your "allowed excludefields" list.